# How to do RegEx search in Atom text editor

Tags: regex

I was just wondering, how can you properly do a RegEx search in atom or any other text editors?

I have a text file with lots of lines like this:

```
<parentId>1B2FC8AD-C8E4-49F3-BB75-8F306C562B27</parentId>
```

I am trying to find all of those lines, and replace the uniqueID with one uniform uniqueID for all, so I am planning to do a search and global replace, but not sure what to put in the "find" area.

I attempted a regex search using `<parentId><.*></parentId>`, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, my text file has entries that look like:

  <parentId>1B2FC8AD-C8E4-49F3-BB75-8F306C562B27</parentId>

Comment: Use `[^<]*(?=</parentId>)`.

Comment: Sir, that worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:
Regular Expression: `^<parentId>.*</parentId>$`
Replace with: your new id